# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Tags: python

I know its a common question but somehow dosnt work for me.
Here is my project structure:

```
MAIN
| --src
     | -- _init__.py
     | -- data 
            | -- __init__.py
            | -- operation.py
      | start
          | __init__.py
          | go.py
```

in file go.py i have:

```
from src.data.operation import X
```

When im starting go file from MAIN directory:

```
python src/start/go.py
```

It throws:
'''
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
'''

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Try to put an __init__.py at the same level as --src ?

Comment: @Mapotofu Nope, still dosnt work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when running script from Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745094/modulenotfounderror-when-running-script-from-terminal)

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that you're running `src.start.go` as if it were a script, i.e. by giving the full path to the `python` command:

```sh
python src/start/go.py
```

This makes Python think this `go.py` file is a standalone script that isn't part of any package. As defined in the docs (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=command%20line), under `<script>`), this means that Python will search for modules in the same directory as the script, i.e. `src/start/`:

> If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the directory
> containing that file is added to the start of `sys.path`, and the file
> is executed as the `__main__` module.

But of course, `src` is not in `src/start/`, so it will throw an error.

The correct way to start a script that is part of a package is to use the `-m` switch ([reference](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=command%20line#cmdoption-m)), which takes a module path as an argument and executes that module as a script (but keeping the current working directory as a module search path):

> If this option is given, [...] the current directory
> will be added to the start of `sys.path`.

So you should use the following to start your program:

```sh
python -m src.start.go
```

Now when `src.start.go` tries to import the `src` package, it will search in your current working directory (which contains the `src/...` tree) and succeed.

---

As a personal recommendation: *don't put runnable scripts inside packages*. Use packages only to store all the logic and functionality (functions, classes, constants, etc.) and write a separate script to run your application how you want it to, putting it *outside* the package. This will save you from these kind of problems, and has also the advantage that you can write several run configurations for the same package by just making a separate startup script for each.

Comment: so how can we fix this then

Comment: He is trying to import a function from that file into another file, will running something like that on the CLI be appropriate.

Comment: @coderboy Yes; the problem is how they're starting the script, not how they're importing the other module.

Comment: 0


Running the command: python -m src.start.go works like charm.

Now, I have 4 GPU machines, and when I try to run my script in distributed mode like that:

python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=4 src.start.go

It throws me an error: 'no module src'

It happens after adding distributed mode. How can I fix it @Anakhand ?

Comment: @Josh, you'll be better off asking a separate question for that, it has probably something to do with how `pytorch` loads modules and how you have configured your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66180118/12568621

> Linux:
> export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/project/"

> Windows:
> set PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/your/project/"

Answer (score -3):

Check the file structure, the first tree should have **init**.py and not *init*_.py

```
MAIN
| --src
     | -- __init__.py
     | -- data 
            | -- __init__.py
            | -- operation.py
      | start
          | __init__.py
          | go.py
```