# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named src

Tags: python, directory-structure, modulenotfounderror

This is the folder structure of my project in python (version 3.9.13):

```
src
    modules
        __init__.py
        fileA.py
    main.py    

tests
    __init__.py
    test_main.py
    test_fileA.py
```

When I run main.py I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named src" in line 4 (in main.py) which contains the following import:

```
from src.modules.fileA import classOfFileA
```

How can i resolve it?

I tried to remove "src" from line 4 but this way I have some problems in tests. In fact in test_main.py the following import fails:

```
from src.main import *
```

with the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049663/python3-6-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-src

Answer (score 0):

You said "When I run main.py ..."

What you want is "When I run src/main.py"

```
$ python src/main.py
```

---

Take a look at `$ python -m site` output.
Your PYTHONPATH env var should mention `.` dot,
the current directory,
and the `site` output should mention the
top level directory of your project.

Invoke your code from the project's top level, and the `.` dot
in the env var will do the rest for you.

---

Similarly,

```
$ python -m unittest tests/test_*.py
```

should work fine.

(Or perhaps you prefer `-m unittest test/test_main.py`,
which is same as `-m unittest test.test_main`.)

Comment: your answer was very helpful, but i had a question: every time i work on a project on a new folder so is it necessary to set the PYTHONPATH on that folder?

Comment: The unix PATH env var sometimes contains `.` dot, denoting "current directory", so that `$ which myscript.sh` might obtain it from wherever you've `cd`'d to. Similarly, PYTHONPATH typically contains `.` dot, so that `import mymodule` succeeds. You don't _have_ to include dot, if you prefer long hardcoded pathnames. When you switch to new folder, `.` dot lets you use that folder. On a slightly separate topic, you probably want a new `poetry` or `conda` virt env for each project, in which case you would adjust path each time you switch projects, e.g. with `$ conda activate myproject`.

Answer (score 0):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "src/utility"))

# Import your Enum classes here as obj_func
import saleslead_utility as obj_func
```

answer -> you objec func to resolve instead of fetching function

Comment: Please format your answer properly.

Comment: Hi Shreyash, welcome to Stack Overflow. I have put triple backticks \`\`\`...\`\`\` around the code so it gets formatted and highlighted properly. You can view the edit history to see what I changed. The final sentence is very short, generally full sentences are easier for readers of this site. But let me repeat, welcome! We look forward to your contributions to this site.