# Python not respecting __init__ on windows, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, import, modulenotfounderror

The following code works on macOS, but not on Windows:

```
src
 ┣ __init__.py
 ┣ greeter.py
 ┗ helper.py
```

greeter.py

```py
from src.helper import world


def hello():
    print("Hello {}".format(world()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello()
```

helper.py

```py
def world():
    return "World"
```

Error on Windows:
**ModuleNotFoundError**

[image]

Python on both is 3.9.13 64bit.

What am i missing here?

Comment: this link must help you [src_ModuleNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049663/python3-6-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-src)

Comment: From the directory where src is, run `python -m src src.greeter`

Comment: "cd src && python -m src src.greeter" --> No module named src

Comment: none of the above does explain, why it works on macOS and not on Windows